# Find credits used per database and schema in Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I am trying to find a way to see how many credits a query from account_usage.access_history or account_usage.query_history has used.
I see there's a table warehouse_metering_history, but it shows credits used per warehouse and I would like to go further than that.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Credits aren’t charged per query, but for the time the warehouse is running. As the warehouse can run multiple queries in parallel, there is no way of allocating costs accurately to a query - though obviously you could come up with your own  allocation rules, if you wanted to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the warehouse metering history is providing information on how many credits a warehouse consumed in an hour. Together with the Query History account usage view you could do the following: Create a CTE querying the Query_History and use the start_time of a query and extract the date and hour portion out of it (e.g. START_HOUR).
For each START_HOUR and warehouse calculate how much all queries took in terms of milliseconds to run (e.g. Duration_Seconds_Total_Warehouse_Hour). You then divide each queries runtime for that START_HOUR and warehouse by the Duration_Seconds_Total_Warehouse_Hour time and get the proportion each query used this warehouse for a specific date and hour. (e.g. Query_Consumption_Portion)
You can then join this CTE-result with the warehouse_metering_history by warehouse_id and Start_Time and multiply the Query_Consumption_Portion of the CTE with the CREDITS_USED used column of the warehouse_metering_history.
You would not be 100% accurate, especially if queries span over multiple hours, but the result would still be pretty accurate.

Here is my sample code:

```
WITH PRE_QUERY_PARTIAL_TIMES AS
    (SELECT
        START_TIME,
        END_TIME,
        TIMESTAMPDIFF('millisecond', START_TIME, END_TIME) AS Duration_Query,
        SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF('millisecond', START_TIME, END_TIME)) OVER (PARTITION BY TO_TIMESTAMP(TO_VARCHAR(START_TIME, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh') || ':00:00'), WAREHOUSE_ID ORDER BY TO_TIMESTAMP(TO_VARCHAR(START_TIME, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh') || ':00:00')) AS Duration_Seconds_Total_Warehouse_Hour,
        TO_TIMESTAMP(TO_VARCHAR(START_TIME, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh') || ':00:00') AS START_HOUR,
        Duration_Query/Duration_Seconds_Total_Warehouse_Hour AS Query_Consumption_Portion,
        QUERY_ID,
        WAREHOUSE_ID
    FROM "SNOWFLAKE"."ACCOUNT_USAGE"."QUERY_HISTORY"
    WHERE WAREHOUSE_ID IS NOT NULL)
SELECT QPT.START_TIME,
    QPT.END_TIME,
    QPT.Duration_Query,
    QPT.Duration_Seconds_Total_Warehouse_Hour,
    QPT.START_HOUR,
    QPT.Query_Consumption_Portion,
    QPT.QUERY_ID,
    WHM.WAREHOUSE_NAME,
    WHM.CREDITS_USED,
    WHM.START_TIME AS START_TIME_WH,
    WHM.END_TIME AS END_TIME_WH,
    WHM.CREDITS_USED*QPT.Query_Consumption_Portion AS Credits_Consumed_By_Query
FROM PRE_QUERY_PARTIAL_TIMES AS QPT
INNER JOIN "SNOWFLAKE"."ACCOUNT_USAGE"."WAREHOUSE_METERING_HISTORY" AS WHM
    ON QPT.WAREHOUSE_ID = WHM.WAREHOUSE_ID
    AND QPT.START_HOUR = WHM.START_TIME;
```

Best regards,

TK