# Segregate Snowflake Credits by Schema

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I would like to understand if there is a way in Snowflake to segregate credit usage by schema - or if this question is not possible to answer at all by the nature of Snowflake.

By that I mean, I have schemas with normalized tables and then I have a schema that contains the output of scheduled tasks in Snowflake. The queries behind the scheduled tasks join multiple tables from multiple schemas so perhaps Snowflake does not track the credit cost due to the resources utilizing each schema.

I'd like to better segregate out not just the most intensive tasks I have w/r/t credit usage but the most expense around which schemas are driving this.

I did see and attempt the query in this SO answer, [Find credits used per database and schema in Snowflake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73064893/find-credits-used-per-database-and-schema-in-snowflake), but it mainly segregates a granular look behind warehouse that doesn't revolve around schemas like the question originally asked.

Comment: The question/answer that you linked to is accurate.  Snowflake credits are based on the duration and size that a warehouse is running.  A warehouse is completely separate from database/schema, so the only way to do what you are asking is based on warehouse compute and an attribution of queries to that compute.  The addition of `access_history` to Snowflake's Account Usage can help you get more granular on what schemas and tables are being accessed in every query, so it might get you closer than the query in the answer on that post.

Comment: As a note, though, best practice for your situation would suggest that you separate your warehouses for the differing types of queries that you want to analyze costs on.  This would make things a lot easier to determine costs and also potentially give you tune your "most intensive tasks" to a different warehouse than your "less intensive tasks".

Comment: Mike's points are gold. The "downside" of separate warehouses per "schema", is if you had sub 1 x-small warehouse, and now to have 3 wharehoses 24x7, you have 3x x-small, your credits will be more. But if you have methods of monitoring/control/etc separating that things, is a great idea.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is NO. You cannot easily attribute the cost of credits to specific schemas.  The only way to ACCURATELY attribute cost is via the WAREHOUSE using SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.WAREHOUSE_METERING_HISTORY

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/warehouse_metering_history

The longer answer:-

It is possible to ESTIMATE the cost of each query from SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.QUERY_HISTORY by taking the EXECUTION_TIME column as a percentage of the total EXECUTION_TIME for the day and multiplying this by the CREDITS_USED_COMPUTE in METERING_HISTORY for the day.

Once you have the ESTIMATED cost per query, you could then then check SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.ACCESS_HISTORY

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/access-history

Which gives the details (Database, Schema, Tables, Columns) for each query.

However, this would probably make the estimate useless as it would be so inaccurate it would provide little value.

Don't forget any Serverless Compute (serverless tasks, Snowpipe, Clustering) has no "warehouse" and therefore cannot be estimated this way.

My thinking is "What problem are you trying to solve"?  Why do you want to attribute credit cost to the schema?  If you can explain that - then perhaps we could suggest an answer.

Hope that helps,

John Ryan